# NSString working once then not working

Tags: ios, nsstring

This is my first time using this site and I am quite new to Objective-c. I'm sure this is a simple question but for some reason I am having a lot of issues. The app is designed to have the user enter a string via textfield, then it will pick the rest of the sentence and display it. The issue appears to be that my *name will be retained after the keyboard method and work once in the changelabel method. Then if i press the button again, invoking the changelabel method, the name appears to have been released and crashes the app.
    #import 
    #import "Array.h"

```
@interface RandomBoredViewController : UIViewController {
UILabel *label;
UIButton *button;
UITextField *textField;
Array *array;
NSString *name;
NSString *description;
NSMutableString *whole;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Array *array;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *whole;

-(IBAction) keyBoard;
-(IBAction) changeLabel;

@end
```

and my .m

```
#import "RandomBoredViewController.h"

@implementation RandomBoredViewController

@synthesize label;
@synthesize checker;
@synthesize button;
@synthesize textField;
@synthesize array;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize description;
@synthesize whole;


-(IBAction) changeLabel {
NSLog(@"Button being pushed");
description = [array getString];
NSLog(@"%@",description);
NSLog(@"%@",name);
name = [NSString stringWithString:name];
whole = [NSMutableString stringWithString:name];
NSLog(@"%@",name);
NSLog(@"%@",whole);
[whole appendString:description];
NSLog(@"%@",name);
NSLog(@"%@",whole);
label.text = whole;
NSLog(@"%@",name);
}

-(IBAction) keyBoard {
name = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
NSLog(@"%@",name);
label.text = [NSString stringWithString: name];
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
array = [[Array alloc]init];
[array createArray];
NSLog(@"%i",[array arrayCount]);
whole = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
name = [[NSString alloc]init];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
[label release];
[button release];
[textField release];
[array release];
//[name release];
[description release];
}

@end
```

Comment: This line seems a bit redundant: `name = [NSString stringWithString:name];`  It may be the source of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking one thing in microcosm, the code you've posted creates two things named `name` — an instance variable and a property.

Instance variables are directly accessed storage. They have no behaviour.

Properties are named attributes accessed via getters and setters. So they may have arbitrary behaviour. They may report the values of instance variables or values calculated from instance variables or values calculated or obtained by any other means. Relevantly, the setters may `retain`, `assign` or act in any other way.

Instance variables may be accessed only by the instance of a class they belong to. Properties are usually intended to be accessed by anyone.

Since retaining is a behaviour and you've ascribed it to your `name` property, setting something to it would result in a `retain`. Instance variables can't have behaviour, so setting a value to it doesn't result in a `retain` or anything else.

As a result, this line:

```
name = [NSString stringWithString:name];
```

Creates a new string and returns a non-owning reference. Which means it'll definitely last for the duration of this autorelease pool (ie, you explicitly may pass it as an argument or return it safely, assuming you haven't taken manual control of your autorelease pools).

You store that reference to your instance variable. Instance variables don't have behaviour so the reference is stored but you still don't own that object. It's still only safe to use for the duration of that autorelease pool.

So when you access it in that method it's safe. When you access it later it's unsafe.

If instead you'd gone with:

```
self.name = [NSString stringWithString:name];
```

Then you'd have set that string to be the new value of the property. Because your property has the `retain` behaviour, you'd subsequently have completely safe access to the string object, until you say otherwise.

Because you've got a property with exactly the same name as an instance variable, you could subsequently access it either as just `name` or as `self.name`. Similarly you could have stored directly to the instance variable rather than via the property if you'd ensured you had an owning reference manually.

As suggested above, use of ARC is a way to get the compiler to figure all this stuff out for you.

That issue is what causes your code to crash — you end up trying to access a reference that has ceased to be valid. If you'd taken ownership of it then it would have continued to exist at least as long as you kept ownership.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. This in depth description is exactly what I need to fix my app and understand the language. This is really my first time posting anything like this online, and it was good to know that my problem was taken seriously and not trolled. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting name to an autoreleased instance of NSString, this is probably what's causing your app to crash.

Use

```
self.name = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
```

Your synthesized mutator will retain the NSString and prevent it from being released.

Comment: Thank you, this was an instant fix. Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this. I'm sure this was one of your easiest things to fix, but it was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try using self.name
sometimes this stuff confuses me as well and for that you might want to consider using arc in which case most of this stuff can be avoided.

when using properties you should always use self.propertyName vs propertyName (only), it uses the accessors (get propertyName, set propertyName) as opposed to directly accessing that pointers value.

take in mind there are 2 exceptions to the rule, init and dealloc which should NOT use self.

```
self.name = [NSString stringWithString:name];
```

you technically should also have an init method
to initialize your variables, and i believe you should call [super dealloc] last not first in your dealloc method, but thats not your problem and might not matter (just what I do when I dont use arc)

Comment: the `self.` stuff is good, but variables are `init`'ed in `viewDidLoad`, no need to `init` them again.

Comment: yes but thats not where they are suppose to be initialized.  but yes, it probably wont matter for smaller/simpler projects

Comment: why is that not where they are "suppose to be initialized."  Seems like as good a place as any other.  Really though, calling something like `self.name = [NSString stringWithString:@"anything"];`  will take care of the `init` for you in the setter that your `@synthesize` created, I believe.

Comment: well from the name (init) used you can tell that it is the intended place to initialize variables.  one of the major reasons in this case is that he could not use his properties or methods externally without calling viewDidLoad first as opposed to calling alloc & init then his class is ready to be used regardless of the context (view or no view being shown).  plus the documentation talks about direct access when initializing values hence why you are not suppose to use self. in init or dealloc.  init methods are made to prepare a class for use, viewDidLoad is made to tell you the view loaded

Answer (score 0):

When you change your instance variable in `changeLabel`, you should release the previous value and retain the new one. You may use the accessors to perform the memory management stuff for you. Also, I think you should invoke `[super dealloc]` **after** releasing the instance variables in your implementation of `dealloc`.

If you're not familiar with Cocoa memory management (and even if you are), the best is to enable ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and let the compiler deal with it.

Comment: Thank you. I looked into ARC and it looks awesome, but i'm still running snow leopard and can't run xcode 4. But thanks